# What's voice leading and how does it work?

Tags: theory, harmony, voice-leading

What's is voice leading and how does it work? I'd really appreciate a thorough answer. What I mean by how it works is how is it achieved and what's the basis of it?

Comment: Check this question and answer out: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7185/voice-leading-confusion?rq=1 "*Most generally, voice-leading is just the way voices move about in a piece. Usually, good voice leading means that each voice feels smooth, atleast somewhat independent, at least somewhat interesting, and supportive of the background harmony and feel of the piece.*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voice leading is where you write harmony as if you have several instruments, each playing an interesting melody (or at least playing a line that, although it may be boring sometimes, is not UN-melodic, leaping all over the place).  The voices, in combination, form chords, but you're not just plonking down one chord after another.